# When trying to migrate I get the error: 'PDOException'

Tags: sqlite, laravel, pdo, laravel-5

When trying to migrate I get the error:

```
 'PDOException' with message could not find driver
```

I'm on an Ubuntu Linux environment. I've configured "sqlite" and if I run sqlite3 from the command line I get to the sqlite shell, so it is correctly installed, but Laravel does not connect to the database!

[image]

Comment: Try outputing `phpinfo()` and make sure you have pdo_sqlite listed.  And also under PDO, be sure sqlite is listed as enabled.

Comment: thanks for your reply,  it is not listed in phpinfo(), what should i do to solve it/

Answer (score 1):

If you have already installed the php_pdo, but it is not showing on your phpinfo(), you might need to add `extension=sqlite.so` to your /etc/php5/conf.d/sqlite.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

pdo_slqite is missing.  Should be installable via...

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

Comment: i already installed this package. Still unable to get pdo_sqlite in phpinfo(). i am not able to understand the problem

Comment: After you installed it, did you restart your webserver?